# Why do I get this retarget to API 10 warning?

Tags: android, api, warnings

I did update Android SDK on Friday and since than I get the warning "This platform is deprecated. Please re-target your app for a `minumum of API-10`" at Visual Studio although my `minSdkVersion is API 8`.

What shall I do?

Comment: drop the support for Android 8

Comment: It says that activity is deprecated... what shall I use instead? That doesn't make sense.